# jQuery Droppable element - conditional drop event based on item dropped

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out.  I'm trying to have a droppable element conditionally fire a different function based on the class of the item dropped.  For the life of me I can't figure out how to do this.  Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/643PC/22/

The pageContainer accepts Rows.  Rows accept Spans.  Spans should accept Actions and Fields and fire a different function based on which item is dropped.  Any ideas?

Finished function with David's help:

```
    function generalDrop(event, ui) {
        var appendTarget = $(this);
        if (ui.draggable.hasClass('field-item')) {
            fieldDrop(event, ui, appendTarget);
        }
        else {
            actionDrop(event, ui, appendTarget);
        }
    }

    function actionDrop(event, ui, appendTarget) {
        $(document.createElement('a'))
            .addClass('btn btn-primary')
            .attr('href', '#')
            .text('Button')
            .appendTo(appendTarget)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your generalDrop function to this:

```
function generalDrop(event, ui) {
    if (ui.draggable.hasClass('field-item')) {
        fieldDrop(event, ui);
    }
    else {
        actionDrop(event, ui);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I copied it into the jsFiddle and ran it and had no luck, no action occurs when dropping either an Action or Field into a span container. Do you have a working copy you can refer me to?

Comment: Yes, here: http://jsfiddle.net/rkLBK/. I didn't try to make your logic in actionDrop or fieldDrop work, just proved that those functions are being called in the proper context. You might need more work in those functions.

Comment: Thanks David, I figured out why I was losing context when trying to run the fieldDrop and actionDrop functions.  It's now working properly!  Appreciate the help!